# Submitting Credentials Step of Connecting Bot to Slack Clarification

Tags: azure, botframework, slack

I am following the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to add my bot to Slack. At the submitting credentials step, I entered the credentials and clicked Save. It says "Follow the instructions to authorize your Slack app's access to your Development Slack Team." Where are these instructions and what exactly do I do here? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the steps in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), these are the instructions you need to follow to authorize your Slack app's access to your Development Slack Team:

- Once you enter the credentials and click on '**Save**', you will be redirected to a  new window which will ask you to confirm your identity.[image]
- Once you click on '**Agree**', it will initiate the process of authorizing the request and will close the current window. Back on the Channels tab in the portal, you can see the following in the green pop-up right above the '**Configure Slack**' heading.
  [image]

  [image]
- Once the channel is validated, the pop-up will disappear.On the Configure Slack page, confirm the slider by the **Save** button is set to **Enabled**.Now, your bot is configured to communicate with users in Slack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It should redirect you to confirm your identity on the new window if you have followed the instructions and entered the credentials correctly. Can you double check the credentials or try creating a new Slack application for the bot? Also, if its still redirecting to a blank page after entering the correct credentials, then the issue on the Slack side with your Slack account. You might have to contact the Slack team regarding this.